# Can we insert duplicate foreign keys of many side in @onetomany table in hibernate?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, duplicates, postgresql-9.1, hibernate-onetomany

As per my requirement i want to save my record in a default table created  by @onetomany mapping, the issue is that i want to  insert  same record multiple times but hibernate is not allowing me to do it and giving following exception:

org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session

### Model

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = 
 CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval=true)
 private List<MasterCode> msCode;

 public List<MasterCode> getMsCode() {
        return msCode;
 }

 public void setMsCode(List<MasterCode> msCode) {
        this.msCode = msCode;
 }
```

### DAO

```
public void saveOrUpdate(User user) {
     Session session=sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
     Transaction tx=session.beginTransaction();
        try {
          session.saveOrUpdate(user);
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
          tx.rollback();
          e.printStackTrace();
        } 
     tx.commit();
}
```

### Controller

```
 User user =new User();
 user.setName("xyz");
 user.setMsCode(selectedMsList);
```

`selectedMsList` contains records of selected `MasterCode` like :[id: 2,code:"xxx"],[id: 3,code:"yyy"],[id:3,code:"yyy"],[id:1,code:"xxx"].

*i want to insert as many times as user is selected this mscodes.*

Please provide me a solution to ignore this and save records.it is very much needed.

Comment: Please add your relevant mapping and the relevant code where you save multiple times

Comment: please look the provided sample code

Comment: wait... you mean you want to insert in a database the same id two times???

[id: 3,code:"yyy"],[id:3,code:"yyy"]